# How to reproduce the night mode animation in Tweetbot 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

It is not difficult to change the background color of the table view and every single cell. The difficult part is to animate this change with a sliding effect. As the dark color slides from the top of the screen to the bottom, you also have to coordinate the color change of the navigation bar and tab bar. Any ideas possible solutions?

Comment: change the settings in the assessibility elements of IOS 9 Tweetbot is a terrible app, it's not that hard to do the same thing they do but without charging money, they are worthless. Assesibility settings allow you to switch the backgroun to black, this isn't hard. there's nothing you do other than hit tthis swtich. Stop respecting stupid apps, they are terrible.

Comment: @Larcerax Can you elaborate more on how I can change the settings?

Comment: Yep, one sec, let me check the settings switch again

Comment: yeah, so if you open general settings in your Iphone, just look in the list for "inverted colors", and flip the switch, this is essentially all that Tweetbot is doing, just inverting colors. now, you can do this one of two ways: 1. someohow acess assesiblity settings in the user's iphone or 2. you can just use appearance sellectors for your entire app and when user flips a swithc, you just invert the colors, and reload views. It would be something like a call to the app delegate or subclassing UIViewControllers with s color switch.

Comment: @Larcerax Sounds like an interesting approach. How do you implement the animations though?